# Eyedropper doesn't copy entire appearence in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, appearance, eyedropper

[Despite manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/appearance-attributes.html), my eyedropper doesn't coppy everything from appearence of one object to another. Here I am copying from bottom left object to top right:

[image]

Only fill color is copied, no any other effects.

How to accomplish?

Comment: Have you double-clicked the Eyedropper Tool and checked its options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Layers Panel to copy Appearance Attributes. Hold "Alt", Left Click + Drag the Appearance circle (in Layers Panel) to the object you want to copy the effects to.

[image: Copy Effects]